# Use wget or curl from python in Windows CMD

Tags: python, curl, wget

I'm pretty new to Python. I have installed `Python 3.7.3` on my Windows and would like to use CMD to run a `.py` file.

The commands are like `py xxx.py` and it is actually for downloading some files from a server.

When it asks "Is it OK to download", I hit yes.

Then a message appeared.

> The script will need curl or wget on the system, please install them
>   first before running the script !

The program will exit then.

But when I try to run `pip install wget` this message appears:

> Requirement already satisfied: wget in
>   c:\users\qin_l\appdata\local\programs\python\python37-32\lib\site-packages
>   (3.2)

And when I input `py -m wget xxx.file`, I can download the file (not the one I want)

I guess the part that cannot go through windows is

```
# Check if curl or wget commands exsit on your computer
if sys.version_info >= (3,0):
status_curl, result = subprocess.getstatusoutput('which curl')
status_wget, result = subprocess.getstatusoutput('which wget')
else:
status_curl, result = commands.getstatusoutput("which curl")
status_wget, result = commands.getstatusoutput("which wget")
```

And correspondingly

```
if status_curl == 0:
    cmd='curl -g "'+cmd+'" -o '+ ncout
  elif status_wget == 0:
    cmd='wget "'+cmd+'" -O '+ ncout
  else:
    sys.exit('\nThe script will need curl or wget on the system, please install them first before running the script !\nProgram will exit now !\n')
```

It seems `wget` can work in Python but not in the py file. I am super confused here. Do I have to install Linux and run the command in Ubuntu?

Comment: `wget` and `curl` is not python script nor module but normal program (.exe) - you have to find it on internet and install it.

Comment: [wget](http://gnuwin32.sourceforge.net/packages/wget.htm), [curl](https://curl.haxx.se/windows/)

Comment: Hi furas, I downloaded wget.exe and put it to system32 folder. When I run wget -h I can see the help information. But when I run my command again it shows The script will need curl or wget on the system, please install them first before running the script ! Program will exit now !

Comment: you may try to install python script again. Or check code in script and see if it use full path to wget - you may have to change it.

Comment: The script is expecting to be run on linux, so there might be other assumptions it has made that prevent it working in windows.

Comment: Hi Damien, it seems to be the case. If I want to run it on linux, do I have to install Ubuntu for Windows 10? Where should I put the py files so bash can read it? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The script you have is expecting `wget` or `curl` to be installed as command line tools, ie. you can run them from the CMD prompt.

Confusingly, there is also a [python package called wget](https://pypi.org/project/wget/), which was installed with `pip install wget`, but it's completely different..

To install command line `wget`, first install [Scoop](https://scoop.sh) using Powershell, then install install `wget` with `scoop install wget`.

Comment: I can run wget -h in command prompt, but still get the error. Maybe I have to run the py file under linux

Comment: If you're able to share the script, we could see what it's expecting. If you have linux easily available it would probably work there.

Comment: I think the key part in the script which seems to be problematic for windows is # Check if curl or wget commands exsit on your computer
  if sys.version_info >= (3,0):
    status_curl, result = subprocess.getstatusoutput('which curl')
    status_wget, result = subprocess.getstatusoutput('which wget')
  else:
    status_curl, result = commands.getstatusoutput("which curl")
    status_wget, result = commands.getstatusoutput("which wget")  What do you think?

Answer (score 0):

I tried to change 'which curl' to 'where curl' and no error messages anymore. But was not able to download the files because "Disabling SSL due to encountered errors".

Turned to I have to install Ubuntu in my computer, and it finally works.

Comment: Changing your OS totally erase the question, and of course packages like `wget` are easily be installed on Ubuntu. I think you should look for "How to install wget on Windows".